# recorrer fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php

porque esto me devuelve el mismo registro todas las veces. Me explico,porque $resultado=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) no avanza de registro siempre es    el mismo.

---

```
$conexion = Conexion::getInstance();
$sql = "Select title from film where title like '%".$filters."%'";
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$sentencia->execute();          
$resultado=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$registros=$sentencia->rowCount();

$films = array();
for($i=0;$i<$registros;$i++){
    $films[$i]['title']=$resultado['title'];
}
 return json_encode($films);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolvi usando while:

```
while($resultado=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $films[]=$resultado;
}
```

Con el for sería:

```
for($i=0;$i<$resultado=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);$i++){
       $films[$i]['title']=$resultado['title'];
}
```

Comment: Aunque si alguien me puede explicar porque no me funciona con el for.

Comment: Vale ya lo resolvi con el for tmb